# How to get previous data before commit?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to get the previous values ​​that were in a specific table before the current changes and before we commit changes, and without store data in backup table.

Maybe that way it will be more clear:

- stage 1: change data in table X without commit
- stage 2: get data before stage 1 without store it in backup folder
- stage 3: commit stage 1 changes.

Comment: Option 1. Before you commit the changes read the existing data and write it out to file. Option 2 use a trigger.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "get data", get it where (some front-end app, a back-end process?) and what do you want to do with it? (show it to some app user, store it somewhere (a table, a file? ... which apparently you don't want)?  Need more info.

Comment: Ok. You might have a stored proc that does some updates. Before you run these updates I'm assuming you have some primary key available. Select the existing data based on the primary key, insert it into some other temporary holding table for you to use however you wish. Now you should have a snapshot of the before data in this holding table.

Comment: Its milions records, I trying to avoid backup table for performance considerations.
My assumption that it is possible, based on so if we try in another session, we get the prev data.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your transaction is designed you could place logic in a trigger. Triggers have access to old and new values. See [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg13trg.htm) for more information (:old and :new).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger
  BEFORE DELETE OR UPDATE ON test_table
  FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO backup_table (col1, col2) VALUES (:old.col1, :old.col2);
END;
```

Comment: The change I do is millions of records and I want to find data which in certain cases from the prevs values. This database process takes more than an hour and sometimes data change in other tables based on tables that change in that process, and i need to review the changes before commit

Answer (score 0):

[The](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10007.htm#SQLRF01708) `RETURNING` clause on an `UPDATE` should be able to do this for you. Unfortunately, I don't know the Oracle syntax for referring to the previous value (in PostgreSQL this would be `OLD.column_name`) but the docs make it sound as if your needs are supported.